# Need to make ViewFlipper invisible after showNext()

Tags: android, events, view, callback, listener

I have a ViewFlipper with two ImageViews. I would like for the second ImageView to display for two seconds then make the ViewFlipper invisible.

Code similar to this:

```
// ...
// flipper is a ViewFlipper with two ImageViews
flipper.setOnClickListener(
  new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      flipper.showNext();
      // need to sleep for two seconds (e.g. Thread.sleep(2000)) after ImageView 
      // is displayed and then call flipper.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }    
  }
);
```

How can I detect that the second ImageView has been drawn? Then I can execute the code to set the ImageView to invisible after sleeping two seconds.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried: Set the transition animations on your view flipper, and then set `animationListener` on them. In `onAnimationEnd` (I believe) use a `post` to a context or `postDelayed` if you have a handler with your two seconds delay, and then `setVisiblity(View.GONE)`

Comment: Clever solution Tom! I was able to get this working using an animation and the onAnimationEnd() event. thanks! I also played around with ViewTreeObserver which is a cool class ... but didn't help me with this particular problem .

Comment: I'm glad. Better add it as an answer then!

Comment: Btw, if this does help, it's useful for other visitors to stack overflow to comment / accept / vote on the various answers. Best indeed, Tom.

Comment: well, i tried to vote your answer up since it was very helpful! My reputation isn't good enough - apparently I need a reputation of 15 to get voting rights. I'll work on being a good citizen. Thanks again for the creative solution Tom.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way of doing this might be:

1. If you don't set the animations on the `ViewAnimator` yourself, [get them](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#getInAnimation%28%29).
2. Set an [animation listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) on your "out" animation.
3. In this animation's `onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)`, remove the visibility from your view- `setVisibility(View.GONE)`. Strictly speaking, to be correct, you want your visibility to end *after* the Animation has finished, and the first moment after the new window is displayed can be accessed using `myFlipper.post(Runnable...)`. *In your case however*, since you want it delayed, you can use `postDelayed(Runnable..., long delay)`.

This would work because you've want to remove visbility right after the first flip. Want to do this after *n* flips. You then would need to use the view traversal functionality (`getChild` etc...) to maintain a counter as to which child is currently in "view". Luckily, much of this code is written for you in the base class. I recommend perusing the [source code here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/widget/ViewAnimator.java#ViewAnimator.0mWhichChild) so you can see how to easily implement this.